# Intellisense supported TextBox in WPf

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, intellisense

I started with wpf 4.0. I have a textBox where i shall enter linq expressions. So i want to enable intellisense support in the textEditor. All i do now is bringing a popUp which has the list of items. Do i have anyother way to do this in WPF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, none of the built-in controls provide Intellisense functionality. It's a feature provided by code editors, and I doubt Microsoft intends for you to re-implement Visual Studio.

You'll have to write it yourself. See here for a sample: [Intellisense-like Method Selection Pop-up Window](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Intellisense_popup.aspx)

A commercial control package is another option. For example: [Actipro's WPF SyntaxEditor](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/dotnet/wpf/syntaxeditor/default.aspx)

Comment: I managed to bring the properties and methods for the properties through reflexion. But the challenge is i need to provide linq expressions also. I read about expression editor in workflow re-hosting. Is there any scope of using that to provide intellisense support in my application. As far i researched , i did not find an implementation.

Comment: @Jose: I'm honestly not sure. I imagine that's possible because [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/HowLINQPadWorks.aspx) does it. It looks like they're already using the Actipro control I recommended in my answer, along with some of the libraries from the [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) project. Since SharpDevelop is open source, you might look into downloading the code and see how they've implemented Intellisense for LINQ. But that's getting pretty far beyond my level of expertise. Good luck! :-)