# Use Visual Studio Code JavaScript IntelliSense (OmniSharp) in own C# projects

Tags: javascript, c#, intellisense, javascript-intellisense, omnisharp

Can anybody tell me if (and how) it is possible to use the Visual Studio Code JavaScript IntelliSense (OmniSharp i think) (or other) in own C# projects?

I have a textbox in which a user can add JS code and it would be nice to support the user with IntelliSense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at this thread, as this seems a duplicate.

[Intellisense supported TextBox in WPf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791209/intellisense-supported-textbox-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

The Intellisense for Javascript projects in VS Code is powered by the typescript compiler and the tools around it, not by Omnisharp (which provides Intellisense for C# projects).

You can integrate it into your own projects through the typescript language service and server. For details you should refer to the typescript documentation: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Architectural-Overview