# ISE Intellisense in WPF

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have a textbox in my Application (WPF). That textbox like a small code editor (for powershell cmdlet). How can i get that textbox displays "intellisense" or "tab-completion" for the user easy to work with powershell cmdlet? Thank you all.

Comment: Have you tried? Can you give your code?

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791209/intellisense-supported-textbox-in-wpf)

> No, none of the built-in controls provide Intellisense functionality. It's a feature provided by code editors, and I doubt Microsoft intends for you to re-implement Visual Studio.
>
> You'll have to write it yourself. See here for a sample: [Intellisense-like Method Selection Pop-up Window](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22803/Intellisense-like-Method-Selection-Pop-up-Window)
>
> A commercial control package is another option. For example: [Actipro's WPF SyntaxEditor](https://www.actiprosoftware.com/)